# RethinkDB - Updating nested array

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, rethinkdb

I have a survey table that looks like so:

```
{
  id: Id,
  date: Date,
  clients: [{
    client_id: Id,
    contacts: [{
      contact_id: Id,
      score: Number,
      feedback: String,
      email: String
    }]
  }]
}
```

I need to updated the `score` and `feedback` fields under a specific contact.  Currently, I am running the update like this:

```
function saveScore(obj){
  var dfd = q.defer();
  var survey = surveys.get(obj.survey_id);

  survey 
    .pluck({ clients: 'contacts' })
    .run()
    .then(results => {

      results.clients.forEach((item, outerIndex) => {
        item.contacts.forEach((item, index, array) => {
          if(Number(item.contact_id) === Number(obj.contact_id)) {
            array[index].score = obj.score;
            console.log(outerIndex, index);
          }
        });
      });

      return survey.update(results).run()
    })
    .then(results => dfd.resolve(results))
    .catch(err => dfd.resolve(err));

  return dfd.promise;
};
```

When I look at the [update](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/) method, it specifies how to update nested key:value pairs.  However, I can't find any examples to update an individual item in an array.

Is there a better and hopefully cleaner way to update items in a nested array?

Answer (score 9):

You might need to get the array, `filter` out the desired value in the array and then append it again to the array. Then you can pass the updated array to the `update` method.

**Example**

Let's say you have a document with two clients that both have a `name` and a `score` and you want to update the score in one of them:

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "name":  "jacob" ,
      "score": 200
    } ,
    {
      "name":  "jorge" ,
      "score": 57
    }
  ] ,
  "id":  "70589f08-284c-495a-b089-005812ec589f"
}
```

You can get that specific document, run the `update` command with an annonymous function and then pass in the new, updated array into the `clients` property.

```
r.table('jacob').get("70589f08-284c-495a-b089-005812ec589f")
  .update(function (row) {
    return {
      // Get all the clients, expect the one we want to update
      clients: row('clients').filter(function (client) {
        return client('name').ne('jorge')
      })
      // Append a new client, with the update information
      .append({ name: 'jorge', score: 57 })
    };
  });
```

I do think this is a bit cumbersome and there's probably a nicer, more elegant way of doing this, but this should solve your problem.

**Database Schema**

Maybe it's worth it to create a `contacts` table for all your contacts and then do a some sort of join on you data. Then your `contacts` property in your `clients` array would look something like:

```
{
  id: Id,
  date: Date,
  clients: [{
    client_id: Id,
    contact_scores: {
      Id: score(Number)
    },
    contact_feedbacks: {
      Id: feedback(String)
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this solution does not allow for a single object in the array to be updated, and changes the ordering of the objects in the array? All objects in the array that match `{ name: 'jorge' }` are filtered out, and then the updated `{ name: 'jorge'}` object is appended to the array.

Answer (score 6):

**database schema**

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "name":  "jacob" ,
      "score": 200
    } ,
    {
      "name":  "jorge" ,
      "score": 57
    }
  ] ,
  "id":  "70589f08-284c-495a-b089-005812ec589f"
}
```

then you can do like this using `map` and `branch` query .

```
r.db('users').table('participants').get('70589f08-284c-495a-b089-005812ec589f')
  .update({"clients": r.row('clients').map(function(elem){
     return r.branch(
      elem('name').eq("jacob"),
      elem.merge({ "score": 100 }),
      elem)})
    })
```

Comment: Definitely a better solution than the top answer's use of "append" which changes the order of objects in the array. However, this solution also doesn't solve the user's question "I need to update the score and feedback fields under a specific contact", and instead updates all contacts named "jacob".

Comment: @tfmontague thank you. am starting to learn rethinkdb lack some main concepts.

Comment: @zabusa very nice answer imo. please see my answer that shows how this technique can be abstracted to perform nested updates easily.

Answer (score 4):

it works  for  me

```
r.table(...).get(...).update({
contacts: r.row('Contacts').changeAt(0,
  r.row('Contacts').nth(0).merge({feedback: "NICE"}))
 })
```

Comment: This only works when we know the position of item in array,

Answer (score 1):

### ReQL solution

Creating a query to update a JSON array of objects in-place, is a rather complicated process in ReThinkDB (and most query languages). The best (and only) solution in ReQL that I know about, is to use a combination of `update`,`offsetsOf`,`do`,`changeAt`, and `merge` functions. This solution will retain the order of objects in the array, and only modify values on objects which match in the `offsetsOf` methods.

The following code (or something similar) can be used to update an array of objects (i.e. `clients`) which contain an array of objects (i.e. `contracts`).

> Where `'%_databaseName_%'`, `'%_tableName_%'`, `'%_documentUUID_%'`, `%_clientValue_%`, and `%_contractValue_%` must be provided.

```
r.db('%_databaseName_%').table('%_tableName_%').get('%_documentUUID_%').update(row =>

    row('clients')
      .offsetsOf(clients => client('client_id').eq('%_clientValue_%'))(0)
      .do(clientIndex => ({

        clients: row('clients')(clientIndex)
          .offsetsOf(contacts => contact('contact_id').eq('%_contactValue_%')))(0)
          .do(contactIndex => ({
            contacts: row(clientIndex)
              .changeAt(contractIndex, row(clientIndex)(contractIndex).merge({
                'score': 0,
                'feedback': 'xyz'
              }))
          })
      }))
)
```

### Why go through the trouble of forming this into ReQL?

```
  survey 
    .pluck({ clients: 'contacts' }).run()
    .then(results => {

      results.clients.forEach((item, outerIndex) => {
        item.contacts.forEach((item, index, array) => {
          if(Number(item.contact_id) === Number(obj.contact_id)) {
            array[index].score = obj.score;
            console.log(outerIndex, index);
          }
        });
      });

      return survey.update(results).run()
    })
```

While the code provided by Jacob (the user who asked the question here on Stack Overflow - shown above) might look simpler to write, the performance is probably not as good as the ReQL solution.

1) The ReQL solution runs on the query-server (i.e. database side) and therefore the code is optimized during the database write (higher performance). Whereas the code above, does not make full use of the query-server, and makes a read and write request `pluck().run()` and `update().run()`, and data is processed on the client-request side (i.e. NodeJs side) after the `pluck()` query is run (lower performance).

2) The above code requires the query-server to send back all the data to the client-request side (i.e. NodeJs side) and therefore the response payload (internet bandwidth usage / download size) can be several megabytes. Whereas the ReQL solution is processed on the query-server, and therefore the response payload typically just confirms that the write was completed, in other words only a few bytes are sent back to the client-request side. Which is done in a single request.

### ReQL is too complicated

However, ReQL (and especially SQL) seem overly complicated when working with JSON, and it seems to me that JSON should be used when working with JSON.

I've also proposed that the ReThinkDB community adopt an alternative to ReQL that uses JSON instead (https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/6736).

The solution to updating nested JSON arrays should be as simple as...

```
r('database.table').update({
  clients: [{
    client_id: 0,
    contacts: [{
      contact_id: 0,
      score: 0,
      feedback: 'xyz',
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Two problems, 1) each time you use `offsetsOf(...)(0)` there's a risk of throwing an error. You can fix that by appropriately using `r.branch` and 2) Your proposed "ReQL is too complicated" JSON query doesn't make sense. Which contact gets updated in which client? contact `0` in client `0`?

Comment: @NathanDrake - (1) Could you explain the risk of throwing an error, and why `r.branch` solves that issue? I don't quite understand. (2) The intent of the code was simply to convey the idea. However, I've added the `client_id` and `contact_id` fields to make the example more literal.

Comment: Well in the event that `offsetsOf(...)` returns an empty result, there will be no `(0)` to return. Ie, `r.expr([1,2,3]).offsetsOf(x => x.gt(3))(0)` results in error, `e: Index out of bounds: 0`. Using `map` mitigates this issue.

Comment: In the updated proposal for the JSON update, you can add `{ client_id, ... }` and `{ contact_id, ...}` to the patch but there's nothing that tells rethinkdb _which_ record in the array to update. You wish for `client_id` and `contact_id` to be used as some sort of index/key, but rethinkdb has no concept of index/key on arrays - only for _tables_.

Comment: edit: You can see the use of `r.branch` in my answer

Comment: @NathanDrake - "but rethinkdb has no concept of index/key on arrays - only for tables" - yeah but that's not what I'm suggesting for an array. The proposal is to use the defined JSON structure, and match it against the element (object structure) in the array. So it's not even about ids, it's about how closely the two structures match.

Comment: @NathanDrake - "Well in the event that offsetsOf(...) returns an empty result, there will be no (0) to return. [And] results in error, e: Index out of bounds: 0". - So what is the problem? If a key-value to be updated doesn't exist, then an error should be thrown, so that the developer can decide how to handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

## Better late than never

I had your same problem and i could solve it with two ways:

#### With specific `client_id`

```
r.db('nameDB').table('nameTable').get('idRegister')
.update({'clients': r.row('clients')
    .map(elem=>{
        return r.branch(
            elem('client_id').eq('your_specific_client_id'),
            elem.merge({
                contacts: elem('contacts').map(elem2=>
                    r.branch(
                        elem2('contact_id').eq('idContact'),
                        elem2.merge({
                            score: 99999,
                            feedback: 'yourString'
                        }),
                        elem2
                    )
                )
            }),
            elem
        )
    })
})
```

#### Without specific `client_id`

```
r.db('nameDB').table('nameTable').get('idRegister')
.update({'clients': r.row('clients')
    .map(elem=>
        elem.merge({
            contacts: elem('contacts').map(elem2=>
                r.branch(
                    elem2('contact_id').eq('idContact'),
                    elem2.merge({
                        score: 99999,
                        feedback: 'yourString'
                    }),
                    elem2
                )
            )
        })
    )
})
```

I hope that it works for you, even when happened much time ago

Comment: This is the cleanest and simplest answer. It's also the most correct! Thank you for sharing this, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

tfmontague is on the right path but I think his answer can be improved a lot. Because he uses `...(0)` there's a possibility for his answer to throw errors.

zabusa also provides a ReQL solution using `map` and `branch` but doesn't show the complete nested update. I will expand on this technique.

ReQL expressions are composable so we can isolate complexity and avoid repetition. This keeps the code flat and clean.

First write a simple function `mapIf`

```js
const mapIf = (rexpr, test, f) =>
  rexpr.map(x => r.branch(test(x), f(x), x));
```

Now we can write the simplified `updateClientContact` function

```js
const updateClientContact = (doc, clientId, contactId, patch) =>
  doc.merge
  ( { clients:
        mapIf
        ( doc('clients')
        , c => c('client_id').eq(clientId)
        , c =>
            mapIf
            ( c('contacts')
            , c => c('contact_id').eq(contactId)
            , c =>
                c.merge(patch)
            )
        )
    }
  );
```

Use it like this

```
// fetch the document to update
const someDoc =
  r.db(...).table(...).get(...);

// create patch for client id [1] and contact id [12]
const patch =
  updateClientContact(someDoc, 1, 12, { name: 'x', feedback: 'z' });

// apply the patch
someDoc.update(patch);
```

Here's a concrete example you can run in `reql> ...`

```js
const testDoc =
  { clients:
      [ { client_id: 1
        , contacts:
            [ { contact_id: 11, name: 'a' }
            , { contact_id: 12, name: 'b' }
            , { contact_id: 13, name: 'c' }
            ]
        }
      , { client_id: 2
        , contacts:
            [ { contact_id: 21, name: 'd' }
            , { contact_id: 22, name: 'e' }
            , { contact_id: 23, name: 'f' }
            ]
        }
      , { client_id: 3
        , contacts:
            [ { contact_id: 31, name: 'g' }
            , { contact_id: 32, name: 'h' }
            , { contact_id: 33, name: 'i' }
            ]
        }
      ]
  };

updateClientContact(r.expr(testDoc), 2, 23, { name: 'x', feedback: 'z' });
```

The result will be

```js
{ clients:
    [ { client_id: 1
      , contacts:
          [ { contact_id: 11, name: 'a' }
          , { contact_id: 12, name: 'b' }
          , { contact_id: 13, name: 'c' }
          ]
      }
    , { client_id: 2
      , contacts:
          [ { contact_id: 21, name: 'd' }
          , { contact_id: 22, name: 'e' }
          , { contact_id: 23, name: 'x', feedback: 'z' } // <--
          ]
      }
    , { client_id: 3
      , contacts:
          [ { contact_id: 31, name: 'g' }
          , { contact_id: 32, name: 'h' }
          , { contact_id: 33, name: 'i' }
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Because he uses ...(0) there's a possibility for his answer to throw errors" - Yeah, but why not just handle the error? If the user is trying to update on a key-value pair that doesn't exist, then an error should be thrown.