# Why can't I append an object to an array in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am trying to append an object into an array in `rethink`.  Here is how I am trying to append it:

```
rethink.table('shifts')
        .get(shiftId)
        .update(row => row("milestones").default([]).append({
            dateAchieved: "2017-01-01",
            phaseType: "TEST"
        })).run(rethinkConnection)
```

The error I get is this:

```
first_error: 'Inserted value must be an OBJECT (got ARRAY):\n[\n\t{\n\t\t"dateAchieved":\t"2017-01-01",\n\t\t"phaseType":\t"TEST"\n\t}\n]',
```

I also tried the same code about, but removed `.default([])`, which did not change anything.

I have tried logging out what `row('milestones')` is and this is the result:

```
var_15("milestone")
```

I was expecting to see an array.  What else is necessary to add an object to an array?  How do I make this work?

Comment: Update takes an object with a key. You are only passing an array. This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265313/rethinkdb-updating-nested-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update document with a document not an array. Your reql should look like this

```
rethink.table('shifts')
  .get(shiftId)
  .update({
    milestones: rethink.row('milestones').append({
      dateAchieved: "2017-01-01",
      phaseType: "TEST"
    })
  })
  .run(rethinkConnection)
```

this is because the `.append` command does not commit data to the database it only returns an in memory modified array